# Can't set background color on body for Framework7 + Vue App

Tags: html, css, vue.js, html-framework-7

For some reason I am unable to set the background color by simple using

```
body {
 background-color: red;
}
```

Inside off my App.vue file.

I can change the background color by using page-content:

```
.page-content {
 background-color: red;
}
```

But this is a bad hack because it also messes up my panels and other components.

Is there a sure-fire way to set background color for F7+Vue apps?

Comment: You can use `!important` with `background-color: red;` like this `background-color: red !important;`

Comment: @RohitVerma  I've already tried that, doesn't work

Comment: try to apply background-color on .views class.

Comment: @Saurabh  .views class?  Where is that defined?  Doesn't ring any bells

Comment: <div class="views"> in this your all view are present under this your main view is present i.e <div class="view view-main" data-page="index"> and under your main view your all content exists i.e navbar, toolbar, pages and page content. So you  can apply background color according hierarchy of elements

Comment: @Saurabh  I tried 
 .views {

     background-color: red !important;
 }
and it didn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set a classname to your page element as `<f7-page class="bg" ..`

and css

```
.bg.page {
  background-color: red;

}
```

Comment: Thanks!  Yours is the suggestion that finally got it to work.

Answer (score 0):

it depends on how you are creating your app, if you want to change a single page but no the others then probably you are either using components or having them in separate files, either way you can use a scoped style bracket to specify some css to apply only to a specific component

```
<style scoped>
    your css here...
    probably...
   .page-content{
    background-color:red;
    }

</style>
```

also a good idea is when you are creating a new page give it an id so you can define styles easier and without some unexpected behaviors using the easier method above (scoped style) then you just style that specific content using 
#yourID